# How to make a feature for derived trait

Tags: rust

I have defined a trait:

```
pub(crate) trait MyTrait
where
   Self: serde::Serialize + for<'a> serde::Deserialize<'a>
   Self: ....
{}
```

and dependency:

```
serde = "1.0"
```

Implementation is:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
....
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct {....}
```

I want to make serde optional.

So first I add a feature for it in toml:

```
....
serde = { version = "1..0", features = ["derive"], optional = true }
...
[features]
serialize = ["serde"]
```

...and removed serde from trait:

```
pub(crate) trait MyTrait
    where
       Self: ....
{}
```

Now I am not sure what changes I need to make in implentation code.

Do I need to define MyStruct 2 times, like this:

```
#[cfg(feature = "serialize")]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct {....}

#[cfg(not(feature = "serialize"))]
pub struct MyStruct {....}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) for that, i.e. the [`cfg_attr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute) attribute.

```rust
#[cfg_attr(feature = "serialize", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
pub struct MyStruct {
    ...
}
```

This is commonly used in other libraries. However, other crates usually name the feature `serde` as well.

You can also includes attributes based on OS, e.g. `#[cfg_attr(windows, derive(...))]`. Basically any `condition` you can put in [`cfg(...)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute) you can put in `cfg_attr(...)`.

In various crates, you run into stuff like this:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "serde", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "debug", derive(Debug))]
pub struct MyStruct {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for inputs. I tried with cfg_attr, but compilation give me error[E0277].

Comment: @Mandroid I need more context than that. My assumption is that you have serialization code elsewhere that attempts to serialize `MyStruct`, while your `serialize` feature is not enabled